# Why are all level sets of this Hamiltonian bounded?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hamilton-equations

Consider the system
$$
\dot{x}=y,\qquad\dot{y}=x^2-x^3.
$$

The Hamiltonian of this system is
$$
H(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}y^2-\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{4}x^4.
$$

> > Show: All level sets of this Hamiltonian are bounded.

Let $c$ be any constant and consider the set $\left\{(x,y): H(x,y)=c\right\}$.

It is to show that this set is bounded. How can I show that?

My first idea is to solve $H(x,y)=c$ for $y$:
$$
y_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{2c+\frac{2}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{2}x^4}.
$$
What could be the next step?

Comment: What's inside that square root has to be positive!

Comment: Why? Aren't complex numbers allowed?

Comment: Usually when we have a Hamiltonian we are talking about a physical system. Positions, velocities and energy cannot be complex!

Comment: So is it just "enough" to say that there is some $x_0$ such that, if $x>\lvert x_0\rvert$, the expression under the root would be negative, since the term $\frac{1}{4}x^4$ is the expression that dominates?

Answer (score 0):

With $p=\dot{y}$ the Hamiltonian reads

\begin{equation*}
H=\frac{1}{2}p^{2}-\frac{1}{3}x^{3}+\frac{1}{4}x^{4}=\frac{1}{2}p^{2}+V(x)
\end{equation*}
Note that the non-negative term $+\frac{1}{4}x^{4}$ dominates the large $x$
behaviour. In this case $H$ has a compact resolvent which leads to the
result that $H$ can only have discrete eigenvalues and no continuous
spectrum. I think you can find these results in the volumes  "Modern
Mathematical Physics " by Reed and Simon.